# RSA Possible Vulnerability?

Tags: rsa

Given c1 = cipher text of m encrypted with n1 and e
Given c2 = cipher text of the same m encrypted with n2 and the same e,
Is it possible to figure out either of the n's or m?
I can't seem to solve for it myself, but I know that doesn't mean it isn't possible!

Comment: This would be more on topic at http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If RSA is done properly (as per [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125)), then no.

If RSA is done *very improperly* (i.e. without any kind of padding), then message reconstruction is possible if you encrypt the same message *m* with *e* distinct RSA keys, provided they all use *e* as public exponent. This is done with the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem): since *n<sub>1</sub>*, *n<sub>2</sub>*... *n<sub>e</sub>* are all relatively prime to each other (otherwise a simple [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) will break two keys, at which point the problem is solved), knowing *m<sup>e</sup>* modulo all the *n<sub>i</sub>* is sufficient to rebuild *m<sup>e</sup>* modulo the *product* of all the *n<sub>i</sub>*. So you recompute *m<sup>e</sup>* modulo *N = n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>...n<sub>e</sub>*. However, *m* is smaller than each *n<sub>i</sub>*, so *m<sup>e</sup>* is smaller than *N*. In other words, you get *m<sup>e</sup>* itself, not *m<sup>e</sup>* modulo some integer. Computing an *e*-th root in the non-modular integers is easy, and this reveals *m*.

I insist, this is **not** a weakness of RSA. Rather, it is an illustration of why RSA, the real one, is not merely a modular exponentiation, but includes a padding step (and that padding includes random bytes, which is *also* important for a completely different reason). The RSA-without-padding is often called "textbook RSA" because most textbooks describe RSA that way.